# Unlink file in PHP, then create new one with file_put_contents

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use `file_put_contents` to put a json file in place, but I am finding that it will not overwrite the existing file.  My thinking at this point was to try and `unlink` the pre-existing file first, and then user `file_put_contents` to create the new one.  For some reason, this does not seem to be working.  I have a feeling that the two operations are happening too quickly, and the second step tries to run before the first step completes.  Here is my code:

```
$filename = '<?php echo site_url() ?>js/salecomps.json';
if (is_readable($filename)) {
    chmod($filename, 0777);     
    unlink($filename);
}

$q = $this->db->query("SELECT RollNum , Address, v2_lat, v2_lng  FROM tblontario WHERE Municipality = 'AJAX' LIMIT 100");           
$json_string = json_encode($q->result(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents('<?php echo site_url() ?>js/salecomps.json', $json_string);
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: just an idea as a quick sanity check, does the code enter the if statement?

Comment: What is the purpose of chmod'ding the file that is then deleted?

Comment: I was using chmod to make sure that the file would be readable.  I thought that unless the file was readable, I would not be able to unlink it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using wrong way to include  `<?php echo site_url()?>`  it will not give you filepath try to change

```
$filename = '<?php echo site_url() ?>js/salecomps.json';
file_put_contents('<?php echo site_url() ?>js/salecomps.json', $json_string);
```

to

```
 $filename = site_url().'js/salecomps.json';
 file_put_contents(site_url().'js/salecomps.json', $json_string);
```

Comment: Best practice would tell you to store the URL in a variable for re-use instead of defining it more than once.

Comment: It is already stored as a variable so technically the `file_put_contents` could be `file_put_contents($filename, $json_string);`

Comment: Actually instead of blindly copying the whole OP's code you could read it at least once and found out that first 4 lines here are useless thus must be removed.